# AST node class generator

Tags: portability, raku

Given two hashes, my script generates two (poorly formatted) C# source files containing some classes that represent several AST nodes a programming language needs and an implementation of the Visitor pattern for each. While I care a lot about the formatting of my *Raku* code, the formatting of the *C# output* is of no particular concern—I let Rider clean it up for me.

My program has one dependency aside from the standard library: version 0.0.6 of the [`Map::Ordered`](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Map%3A%3AOrdered%3Azef%3Azef%3Alizmat) module (installable using `zef install --/test "Map::Ordered:ver<0.0.6>:auth<zef:lizmat>"`).

It also assumes your terminal supports ANSI colors (and that you want to see them). By default, the script writes the files to the `src` directory relative to the current working directory, but you can specify a different directory using the `-o`/`--out-dir` option.

When you run it, it looks like this:

[image: ✓ Wrote Expr classes to src/Expr.cs ✓ Wrote Stmt classes to src/Stmt.cs]

([I've also uploaded the output files to GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/heyajulia/2e1cc2f6fb9a852f2e50f0096e37589a), should you want to see them.)

## The code

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

use Map::Ordered:ver<0.0.6>:auth<zef:lizmat>;

unit sub MAIN(Str :o(:$out-dir) = 'src');

my %exprs is Map::Ordered =
        Binary => [left => 'Expr', operator => 'Token', right => 'Expr'],
        Grouping => [expression => 'Expr'],
        Literal => [value => 'object?'],
        Unary => [operator => 'Token', right => 'Expr'];

my %stmts is Map::Ordered =
        ExpressionStatement => [expression => 'Expr'],
        Print => [expression => 'Expr'];

generate :base-class('Expr'), :classes(%exprs), :$out-dir;
generate :base-class('Stmt'), :classes(%stmts), :$out-dir;

sub generate(:$base-class!, :%classes!, :$out-dir!) {
    my $source = '';

    $source ~= qq:to/END/;
    namespace Lox;

    internal abstract class $base-class \{
    END

    for %classes.kv -> $class-name, @fields {
        my @types = @fields.map: *.value;
        my @names = @fields.map: *.key;
        my @names-and-types = flat @names Z @types;

        my $fields = format(-> $type, $name { "internal $type {$name.tc} \{ get; \}" }, @names-and-types);
        my $parameters = format(-> $type, $name { "$type {rename-reserved-word($name)}" }, @names-and-types, ', ');
        my $initializers = format(-> $name { "{$name.tc} = {rename-reserved-word($name)};" }, @names);

        $source ~= qq:to/END/;
        internal class $class-name : $base-class \{
            $fields

            internal {$class-name}($parameters) \{
                $initializers
            }

            internal override T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
        }
        END
    }

    $source ~= qq:to/END/;
    internal interface IVisitor<T> \{
        {format({ "public T Visit($^type expr);" }, %classes.keys)}
    }

    internal abstract T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor);
    }
    END

    my $path = IO::Spec::Unix.catpath($, $out-dir, "$base-class.cs");

    spurt $path, $source;

    say "\e[1;32m\c[CHECK MARK]\e[0m Wrote \e[36m{$base-class}\e[0m classes to \e[1;4m$path\e[0m";
}

sub rename-reserved-word($identifier) { $identifier eq 'operator' ?? '@operator' !! $identifier }

multi sub format(&fn where *.signature.params == 1, @xs, $sep = "\n") { @xs.map(&fn).join($sep) }

multi sub format(&fn where *.signature.params == 2, @xs, $sep = "\n") { @xs.map({ fn($^b, $^a) }).join($sep) }
```

The only line I'm *really* not sure about is this one:

```
my $path = IO::Spec::Unix.catpath($, $out-dir, "$base-class.cs");
```

It feels strange to have to use a platform-specific function right there in the middle of a script that is otherwise pretty platform-agnostic, but I couldn't find a function in the standard library that does the right thing across all platforms. In a review, I'd like for that to be addressed, as well as the usual stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `IO::Path`

> my $path = IO::Spec::Unix.catpath($, $out-dir, "$base-class.cs");

You need to work with [`IO::Path`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path) type. You can do `$out-dir.IO.add: "$base-class.cs"`, but I recommend doing the IO part in `MAIN`s signature.
Also your code doesn't check if the `$out-dir` exists. So I would make these changes:

```
unit sub MAIN(IO::Path(Str) :o(:$out-dir) = 'src');
```

```
$out-dir.mkdir: 0o755 unless $out-dir.d;
my $path = $out-dir.add: "$base-class.cs";
```

#### `format` function

There is no need to use `where` clauses in your signature, you can specify the singature of `&fn`. You can also drop the `sub` and `&fn` parameters:

```
multi format(&fn:($), @xs, $sep = "\n") { @xs.map(&fn).join($sep) }

multi format(&fn:($, $), @xs, $sep = "\n") { @xs.map(&fn).join($sep) }
```

If you do that, then there's no need for a `multi`:

```
sub format(&fn:($, $?), @xs, $sep = "\n") { @xs.map(&fn).join($sep) }
```

#### If you don't know

I'll mention some things that can be personal preferences, but maybe it can be of value if you don't know them already.

You can enable/disable things in [quoting constructs](https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting), so you can disable closures if you are not going to use them, so you won't have to escape braces:

```
$source ~= qq:!c:to/END/;
namespace Lox;

internal abstract class $base-class {
END
```

You can use single quotes and temporary use interpolation in it:

```
$source ~= q:to/END/;
internal interface IVisitor<T> {
    \qq｢{format({ "public T Visit($^type expr);" }, %classes.keys)}｣
}

internal abstract T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor);
}
END
```

You can call methods in strings:

```
qq:!c｢internal $type $name.tc() { get; }｣
```

Same for functions:

```
"$type &rename-reserved-word($name)"
```

**Update:**
There is no need to declare/initialize `$source` separately:

```
my $source = qq:to/END/;
namespace Lox;

internal abstract class $base-class \{
END
```

#### Alternative solutions

With your format function you're doing extra iterations, this can be a design decision, but you can do everything in one loop.

```
for %classes.kv -> $class-name, @names-and-types {
    my (@fields, @parameters, @initializers);
    for @names-and-types -> (:key($name), :value($type)) {
        @fields.append: qq:!c｢internal $type $name.tc() { get; }｣;
        @parameters.append: "$type &rename-reserved-word($name)";
        @initializers.append: "$name.tc() = &rename-reserved-word($name);";
    }

    $source ~= qq:to/END/;
    internal class $class-name : $base-class \{
        @fields.join("\n")

        internal {$class-name}(@parameters.join(', ')) \{
            @initializers.join("\n")
        }

        internal override T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
    }
    END
}
```

You can eliminate the `Map::Ordered` dependecy by using Arrays/Lists the way you did for inner lists and put your base classes in one `Map`:

```
my %base-class is Map =
    Expr => [Binary => [left => 'Expr', operator => 'Token', right => 'Expr'],
             Grouping => [expression => 'Expr'],
             Literal => [value => 'object?'],
             Unary => [operator => 'Token', right => 'Expr']],
    Stmt => [ExpressionStatement => [expression => 'Expr'],
             Print => [expression => 'Expr']];

for %base-class.kv -> $base-class, @classes {
    generate :$base-class, :@classes, :$out-dir;
}
```

Then you can also eliminate the `format` call for `IVisitor` and remove the `format` function:

```
my @visits;
for @classes -> (:key($class-name), :value(@names-and-types)) {
    my (@fields, @parameters, @initializers);
    for @names-and-types -> (:key($name), :value($type)) {
        @fields.append: qq:!c｢internal $type $name.tc() { get; }｣;
        @parameters.append: "$type &rename-reserved-word($name)";
        @initializers.append: "$name.tc() = &rename-reserved-word($name);";
    }

    $source ~= qq:to/END/;
    internal class $class-name : $base-class \{
        @fields.join("\n")

        internal {$class-name}(@parameters.join(', ')) \{
            @initializers.join("\n")
        }

        internal override T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
    }
    END

    @visits.append: "public T Visit($class-name expr);"
}

$source ~= qq:to/END/;
internal interface IVisitor<T> \{
    @visits.join("\n")
}

internal abstract T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor);
}
END
```